# How to select which line to scrape from a file with Xidel?

Tags: web-scraping, cmd, xidel

If you have a text file `file.txt` with multiple lines of text e.g.

```
asd asd
asdasd asdasd
```

How do I select that I want to scrape line 2 `asdasd asdasd`? And select line 1 later on etc.

`for /f %a in ('^" xidel --data=file.txt --extract=$raw ^"') do set "variable=%a"` extracts only first word from first line, it skips what's after the first whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, specifying `--data` isn't necessary:

```
xidel --help | FIND "--data"
--data=<string>                         Data/URL/File/Stdin(-) to process
                                        (--data= prefix can be omitted)
```

> *How do I select that I want to scrape line 2 `asdasd asdasd`? And select line 1 later on etc.*

You could use [`x:lines($raw)`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-lines) for that. It's a shorthand for `tokenize($raw,'\r\n?|\n')` and turns `$raw` into a sequence where every new line is another item. Then simply select the 1<sup>st</sup>, or 2<sup>nd</sup> item:

```
xidel -s file.txt -e "x:lines($raw)[2]"
asdasd asdasd
```

> *`for /f %a in ('^" xidel --data=file.txt --extract=$raw ^"') do set "variable=%a"` extracts only first word from first line, it skips what's after the first whitespace?*

It's because if you don't set a delimiter, then it defaults to `<space>` and `<tab>`:

```
FOR /? | FIND "delimiter"
        delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
                          default delimiter set of space and tab.
```

So you could do:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A in ('xidel -s file.txt -e "x:lines($raw)[2]"') DO SET variable=%A
```

Or export the variable with `xidel`:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A in ('xidel -s file.txt -e "variable:=x:lines($raw)[2]" --output-format^=cmd') DO %A
```